# Print Web page on 4 inch printer from mobile

Tags: javascript, java, mobile, printing

I am developing a mobile web application. On the form when the user press Print button I need to print the page on a 4 inch printer. 
My question is how can I connect to the printer from the mobile web browser(may be using bluetooth, USB).
My application will be running on all type of smart phones(Andriod , IOS, Windows, BB etc).

Comment: how about an HTML-formatted email sent to a printer that has an email address to talk with?

Comment: sounds good...but pls can you elaborate it...

Comment: 'Too Broad' by a mile and unclosable due to bounty.

Comment: each platform will have native api you could implement your functionality using those. For android- http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html#Printing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately android and ios lack the concept of a printer driver so there is no native and widely supported way to print from mobile devices.

However there are a couple of other options to consider:

1. Rely on the user to have an app installed for their preferred printer (this probably is not a satisfactory solution as these apps often integrate poorly with mobile web browsers)
2. Target the (fairly common) printers which support email printing, that is allow the users to enter the email address for their printer and then send an email to that address containing whatever it is that you wish to print (for anything other than plaintext you will need to send a multipart email with html content)

Comment: There are certain applications that do the trick of what printer drivers do. But not all of the printers support direct phone printing.

Comment: but many companies use thermal printers for printing from android mobiles

Answer (score 4):

The easiest thing to do is use a service like [Google Cloud Print](http://www.google.co.uk/cloudprint/learn/).

Once the user has completed the action on the app (iPhone, Android, BB) or web browser, you can then submit the data to a printer of your choice.  There is [full documentation available](https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/gadget).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not all the printers are supported by Android. 
But if you have a back-end, get a wifi printer and print it using the wifi-printing preferences from the back-end, trigger of course is from the mobile.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a better fit:

Use a print server - a separate computer that accepts simple printing messages from your app.  The print server can house the drivers for the printer and take care of rendering.  You can write a small service application to listen for jobs from the app.

Android wasn't designed to talk to printers.

Answer (score 0):

try iprintmarvel printer it is very easy to integrate with android/java mobiles

Answer (score -2):

Use javascript to print the page from browser, but your phone must be connected to a printer.
Just try this line of code on any button click event.

```
window.print();
```